# How to create and navigate instantly to a directory with Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell

I need to create and navigate to a directory with one line of command. And it needs to be inside a function. I'm new to terminal and shell scripting and don't know much about it.

My process goes like this:

I write the name of the directory and it is stored to `$dirname` variable, and then type "create" and it is stored to another variable named `$thecommand`, to create the directory with the name I gave, and navigate to it.

I have a `create()` function. Inside the function I did `mkdir ./$dirname`, and then `cd $dirname`. Then I applied a condition: if what the user wrote in `$thecommand` variable (BTW both `$dirname` and `$thecommand` are read, so the user writes the value) is equal to "create".

The directory was created, but it didn't navigate to it. So I tried creating an alias `p="$dirname"`, and applied the alias in the function, still, it created the directory, but didn't navigate!

I would appreciate if someone helped me with this.

Here is my code:

```
echo "Write Folder name"
read dirname
echo "Write -create- to create the folder"
read thecommand

p="$dirname"

function create() {
    mkdir ./"$p"
    cd "$p"
}

if [ "$thecommand" == "create" ]
then
    create
fi
```

Comment: A good place to start is tracing execution with `bash -x yourscript`. BTW, note that `cd` only applies within the shell running your script, **not** the shell that *started* your script.

Comment: ...so, where/how are you testing if the directory changed? If you want it to be changed *for the rest of your script* and it isn't, that's a bug. If you want it to be changed *after your script exits*, that's impossible if you keep your script in an interpreter separate from the interactive shell that invoked it (and we have lots of duplicates for questions asking that).

Comment: ...as another aside, the only POSIX-specified string comparison operator is `=`, not `==`. The latter is a common extension, but won't work on minimal shells like dash, so it's good practice to be in the habit of using the former.

Comment: Charles Duffy, when I execute the script on terminal, I want it to navigate to the  created directory when i create it. And when I execute it, the folder is created, all good, but the path wasn't navigated there (in the sense that when i want to create another file direct from terminal, for example "touch test.txt", it's won't create on the new folder, but on the one I was from the beginning). I didn't mean to complicate it too much, I hope you understood me. Btw thanks for the comparison operator tip!

Comment: You *cannot* change your interactive shell's working directory from a script run in a subprocess, full-stop. (You can write a function *executed in the interactive shell itself* that does that, or you can source the script into the interactive shell so it runs there locally, but it has to be run *in* the interactive shell to change the interactive shell's working directory).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

First, just modifying the `mkdir` function in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`

```sh
function mkdir() {
  command mkdir -p $1  # This creates the folder
  command cd $1        # Then it immediately switches
  command pwd          # Remove this if you don't need confirmation. This just prints out current directory
}
```

If you don't want that to happen *every* time, you can just change the function name to `create` or whatever you prefer.

```sh
function create() {
  command mkdir -p $1     # Note: the `-p` flag just creates a folder, 
                          # like if you do `mkdir test/more` 
                          # you will get an error that it is not valid. 
                          # This does not change a regular `mkdir` command

  command cd $1
  command pwd
}
```

Or, you could just `cd` into the newly created folder

Comment: Quote `"$1"` or this will all behave badly with names with spaces.

Comment: Also, note that `function funcname() {` is merging two different function declaration syntax forms -- the legacy ksh `function funcname {` and the POSIX `funcname() {` -- in a way that isn't compatible with *either* legacy ksh or POSIX. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: I'd also consider putting `|| return` on any command that should cause the function to bail out should it fail (if `mkdir -p` fails, you presumably don't want to go through with the `cd`).

Comment: If i make these changes in .bashrc or .bash_aliases, does that mean that only my computer can recognize this function? And if another computer tries to execute the script, it i won't work, right? Because this script needs to be executable in every computer